# Retrieve id from a string

Tags: java, android

```
String messageId = "007_random-com-usa-9qwerty-abc-1a2b3c";
```

I am getitng this messageId in this format from a provider.

```
"username_company-name-country-code-123random-abc-num"
```

But I am not sure how to retrieve the company id (school-name-country-code) from it.

```
String[] messageIdDetails = schoolDetailsObject.getString("messageid").split("_");
Int userId = Integer.parseInt(messageIdDetails[0]);
String companyId = messageIdDetails[1]; // how to get the company id from the rest of the string?
```

I am expecting to get only the company id from the rest of the string.

Comment: You already know how to split a string; hopefully you know that `_` is different from `-`.

Comment: how can i differentiate the rest of the string? it has both the company id and random characters and they connected by "-"

Comment: Split.  The.  String.  On.  `-`.

Comment: The company id is company-name-country-code.
if i split the string with "-", how can i get the whole company id again?

Comment: Re-assemble the pieces.

Comment: 2 options, 1 if you split by - you get array of String (String[]) if you combine String[0] to relevant index (which should be 3 according to you) while adding - separator you should get the desired outcome.
Option 2 would be to simply using substring to take only the relevant part of the String, assuming you know how many characters are irrelevant (or from which index of - it's irrelevant and then you can count the needed letters to be removed)

Answer (score 1):

When you split, you create an array of the split elements (in this case Strings). Simply join together the elements in the array with concatenation.

```
 String messageId = "007_random-com-usa-9qwerty-abc-1a2b3c".split("_")[1];

        String[] messageIdDetails = messageId.split("-");

        String companyId =
                        messageIdDetails[0] + "-"
                        + messageIdDetails[1] + "-"
                        + messageIdDetails[2] + "-"
                        + messageIdDetails[3];
```